# How to save data from textboxes by linking comboboxes and checkboxes into richtextbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a scheduler where data I entered below on two textboxes have to appear according to the Day or week and Time values. I've tried with the following code, but didn't work.

```
private void btnEnterData_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (((cmbDayWeek.SelectedIndex == 0) && (chb910.Checked == true)))
    {
        rtb1.Text = (tbxMedNumAppn.Text + tbxDocSpecAppn.Text);
    }
    else if (((cmbDayWeek.SelectedIndex == 0) && (chb1011.Checked == true)))
    {
        rtb7.Text = (tbxMedNumAppn.Text + tbxDocSpecAppn.Text);
    }
    return;

    //and codes all the way down
}

private void btnSavePatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((cmbDayWeek.SelectedIndex == 0) && (chb910.Checked == true)))
    {
        rtb1.Show();
    }

    if (((cmbDayWeek.SelectedIndex == 0) && (chb1011.Checked == true)))
    {
        rtb2.Show();
    }

    // codes all the way down
}
```

P.S. I'm assuming that I have to use If/Else statement, but I can't get the logic fully :(

Image of the scheduler:

[image]

Comment: Please indent all lines of C# code with at least 4 spaces (doing so triggers the nice formatted-as-code output)

Comment: Understanding your question requires alot of assumptions, could you rephrase the question or provide a bit more information? What is your actual problem? Are the RichTextBoxes not showing? Are they not filled with text? Are the RichtTextBoxes supposed to be inside the grey squares? Are they numbered left-right-top-bottom? Why does EnterData take `rtb7` when `(((cmbDayWeek.SelectedIndex == 0) && (chb1011.Checked == true)))` and SaveData `rtb2`? Please ellaborate

Comment: Look, when I fill the textboxes, select from comboboxes and tick a time, the information on the textboxes should appear on the specific grey square (referring to the date and time I chose). Now, the problem is, gray squares are not accepting more than one info